# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Page' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am migrating my solution from CRM 8.2 to CRM v9. I am trying to retrieve multiple records in CRM. The same JavaScript code that I am using in my CRM v9 environment was working fine when I was using this in CRM 8.2 environment.

In CRM v9 I am getting following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Page' of undefined at eval (eval at
>   (http://vtdemo/VTd365dev/WebResources/vrp_/Disposition/js/Disposition.js:13:1),
>   :1:20) at HTMLDocument.
>   (http://vtdemo/VTd365dev/WebResources/vrp_/Disposition/js/Disposition.js:13:1)
>   at j
>   (http://vtdemo/VTd365dev/WebResources/vrp_/Common/js/jquery_1.11.2.js:2:27295)
>   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]
>   (http://vtdemo/VTd365dev/WebResources/vrp_/Common/js/jquery_1.11.2.js:2:28108)
>   at Function.ready
>   (http://vtdemo/VTd365dev/WebResources/vrp_/Common/js/jquery_1.11.2.js:2:29942)
>   at HTMLDocument.J
>   (http://vtdemo/VTd365dev/WebResources/vrp_/Common/js/jquery_1.11.2.js:2:30308)

I do not know why is this happening. May be this thing is not supported in CRM v9 anymore if that is the case then how i can make it work?

I am using below code where error is coming,

```
var userLcid = Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid();
```

Comment: Looks like `Xrm` == `null`. You need to investigate why that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved the desired result by first importing the library inside my HTML web resource,

```
<script src="../../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And after some research, I found out that the **GetGlobalContext** function returns the same context object found in the **Xrm.Page.context.**

So, then I used it in my JS like below,

```
var context = GetGlobalContext();
var userLcid= context.getUserLcid();
```

And it worked fine and I achieved my result.

PS: Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly call Xrm.Page in 9.1 Version. Please refer the official Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming).
You will need to pass FormContext [(link for reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/clientapi-execution-context) and replacment for Xrm.Page is something like below

```
ExecutionContext.getFormContext
```

and to get user langauge Id
Before 9.0

```
Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid
```

on and After 9.0 changes as below

```
globalContext.userSetings.languageId
```

Comment: I am getting an error, ExecutionContext is not defined

Comment: Did you refrerred the 2nd link,
Also you will have to adjust your Js function For Ex: Function test(ExecutionContext){
// do something
}

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by making sure that the option to transfer the context of execution as the first parameter was ticked.

[image]